# Xpath Contains value or not PHP if / else condition

Tags: php, dom, xpath, file-get-contents

Trying to find contents inside any website or not. If content present then needs to do something else some other thing.

Xpath | PHP

```
   <?php 

     //Load the HTML page
     $html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
     //Parse it. Here we use loadHTML as a static method
     //to parse the HTML and create the DOM object in one go.
     @$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

     //Init the XPath object
     $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

     $vals = $xpath->query( '//script[not[contains(text(), "sample")]]' );

        if (($vals) > 0) {

           echo 'finding text, not in the website';

        } else {

           echo "Test";

         }

    ?>
```

I am not able to explore how to do the if else condition for this.

Comment: please try //script[not[contains(., "sample")]]

Comment: Hi I have added //script[not[contains(text(), "sample")]  but the problem with if / else part

Comment: `DOMXPath::query` returns a `DOMNodeList`, and that has a `length` property … so if you want to know if any elements where found or not, use that to check.

Comment: you can use count($vals)

Answer (score 0):

you can use count()

```
if ((count($vals)) > 0) {
    echo 'finding text, not in the website';
} else {
    echo "Test";
}
```

Comment: Hi I have tested this with two HTML file, 1 HTML file have the text and another one doesn't have the text but the result always returns else part "Test" ..

Comment: can you echo count($vals);

Comment: This is the echo of $vals - "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\hubs\login.php on line 43"